# How to use wildcard for multiple events in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to feed in all input matching a pattern using wildcards. Example:

```
$ cat file_lister.sh
echo $1

$ ls *.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

$ ./file_lister.sh ./*.txt
file1.txt
```

But I expected, my script to print

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Comment: The echo will put all the names on one line. The scripted command should be: printf '%s\n' "$@"

Comment: The issue is that the shell running file_lister expands the wildcards, which go into the script as $1 $2 $3. If you single-quote the './*.txt' argument, it will be $1 to the command-line script and be expanded by the other shell that is running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your script:

```
$ ./file_lister.sh ./*.txt
```

The shell expands `./*.txt` to `./file1.txt ./file2.txt ./file3.txt`, so after the expansion you really end up executing:

```
$ ./file_lister.sh ./file1.txt ./file2.txt ./file3.txt
```

Your script prints the first argument:

```
echo $1
```

`$1` corresponds to the first argument passed to the script, which in this case is `./file1.txt` -- I'd expect to see that instead of just `file1.txt` (unless you really ran `./file_lister.sh *.txt`).

As others have suggested in the comments, if you want to print *all* of the arguments instead of the first, there are number of things you can do.  The easiest is to change `$1` (the first argument) to `$@` (all arguments).

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

See [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-a-bash-script) for more information on processing arguments in a script.

Comment: I believe they expect the output to be one name per line, in which case `printf '%s\n' "$@"` would be better than `echo "$@"`, which outputs all the arguments with a space between each.